# How to Create android supported video file (e.g. mp4) using InputStream object in Android

Tags: java, android

In my Android app I'm downloading Video file using Quickblox API, on successful download I'm getting file content in the form of InputStream object now, using that InputStream object I wants to create android supported Video file and stored it on to the SDCard but I don't know how to create Video file using InputStream object. Please see the following code where I'm getting InputStream object.

```
 QBContent.downloadFileTask(fileId, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<InputStream>() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InputStream inputStreamObject, Bundle params)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSuccess(inputStreamObject, params);



            });
     }
```

Please help. Thank you..!

Comment: Did you read InputStream documentation?

Answer (score 2):

If the `inputStreamObject` is the content of an mp4 file, you could simply save the input stream to a file. That's your mp4 .

```
public static final String PREFIX = "myMusicfile";
    public static final String SUFFIX = ".mp4";

    public static File stream2file (InputStream in) throws IOException {
        final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX);
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        }
        return tempFile;
    }
```

Hope it help :)
Thanks

Comment: @Feytality yes it did.